# Angularjs ng-class class order/precedence

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

EDIT:It turns out to be a confusion on my side, pls see my own answer.

I came across a strange behavior when attempting to reorder the precedence of multiple classes in ng-class.

```
ng-class="{'e':($index%2>0),'btn-primary':($index>3)}"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6JjFM/1/

The thing is that no matter how you change the order of the expressions in ng-class it always seems to apply the class which is last in the stylesheet(ie in the css if you put the .btn-primary below .e it will start using the background-color of .btn-primary).
Same thing occurs if I use the ng-class-even to put the .e class.
If you actually inspect the code with chrome it shows up the order to be "btn-primary e" however the background-color of .e does not override the one of btn-primary.

Is there some way to change the precedence of the classes in the ng-class using angular without using css tricks such as !important etc.

Comment: You don't want btn-primary to override e ?

Comment: ng-class="{'btn-primary':($index>3 && $index%2!=0),'e':$index%2==0}" try this

Comment: "order/precedence" was all I needed to see to figure out my problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not actually on `ng-class`, as I see he work as how he design for.

**Solution 1:**
Yes, use CSS trick. Add below style to your stylesheet:

```
.e.btn-primary{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

It will now use `e` background color.

**Solution 2:**
Use `ng-style`

```
<li 
    class="li" 
    ng-class="{'btn-primary':($index>3),'e':($index%2>0)}" 
    ng-repeat="row in rows"
    ng-style="$index%2>0 && {'backgroundColor': '#F5F5F5'}"
    >{{row}}</li>
```

`ng-style` will add inline style to the element, and it will overwrite onfile stylesheet.

Comment: Yes you are right that my problem is not actually the ng-class as the classes' style precedence are applied indeed in the order they are defined in the css stylesheet. Perhaps I got confused because of being used to adding classes dynamically to elements. Nevertheless using the first or the second solution would not help in my case as .e actually has a hover state which changes the background-color as well. So in my case using the answer from above of Aditya Ponkshe to not apply the .btn-primary class in case of .e is applied will work better.

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behavior. The order of the classes in ng-class won't matter. CSS looks at specificity and if that is same it applies the class that appears 2nd. In your case, .e and .btn-primary have the same specificity so the class that appears later in the css will override the earlier class (if they both change the same attributes).

See here for an example of how I changed the specificity to ensure the class that appears first gets applied...

I've increased the specificity of btn-primary by adding div to it. The background of the div hence appears in blue.

index.html:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

    div.btn-primary {background-color: blue;}
    .e {background-color: red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body >
    <script src= "angular.js"></script>

    <script src= "script.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller='TeamController'>
    <div ng-class="{'e':value%2>0, 'btn-primary':value>3}">
        hello world
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('TeamController', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = 7;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are absolutely right and I thank you for them!

My confusion comes from working too long with jquery and dynamically adding classes on events to elements.

```
$('#el').click(function(){
        $('#el').addClass("two")
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Gtk6/

What I realized the moment I wrote down my question, is that in this case ng-repeat re-renders the page each time something changes(in the scope based on some event) and conforms to the stylesheet order and the specificity of each class.
Thanks again!